# Linux Bash show multiple elements from Array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Is there a way to show multiple elements from an array and how to show all of them using a variable for the index, for example:

Here I can get the elements :

```
ANIMALS=('DOG' 'CAT' 'CAW' 'BIRD')
INDEX=1
echo ${ANIMALS[$INDEX]}

CAT
INDEX=2
echo ${ANIMALS[$INDEX]}

CAW
```

Question 1, how can I get all elements using the variable index? I'm assigning it the value @, but I'm getting the following error:

```
INDEX=@
echo ${ANIMALS[$INDEX]}
-bash: @: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "@")
```

Expected Resutl: show all the elements in the array

Question 2, How can I show multiple elements , for example if I want to show elements in the index 0 and 3, something like:

```
INDEX="0  3"
echo ${ANIMALS[$INDEX]}
```

Expected result:

```
    DOG BIRD
```

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: In general, use `"${!array[@]}"` to get the list of keys. In your case use `INDEX=("${!ANIMALS[@]}")`.

Comment: `@` is a special symbol in this context. You can only pass it literally, not via a parameter expansion `$INDEX? .

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use a list of numbers and iter inside it:

```
$ ANIMALS=('DOG' 'CAT' 'CAW' 'BIRD')
$ INDEXES=(1 3)
$ for key in "${INDEXES[@]}"; do echo "${ANIMALS[$key]}"; done
```

The result of this should be:

```
CAT
BIRD
```

Comment: `FOR` and `IN` need to be lower-case -- this isn't SQL; operators are case-sensitive here. And quoting matters. `${array[@]}` without the quotes is identical to `${array[*]}` without the quotes; you only get the additional correctness of the `@` operator when you quote `"${array[@]}"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, I have already changed it. Thanks

Comment: Similarly, `echo ${ANIMALS[$key]}` hits the problems described in [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and should be `echo "${ANIMALS[$key]}"`.

Comment: I added quotes. Otherwise `${ANIMALS[@]}` will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, you can use the "${ANIMALS[@]}" syntax to iterate through all the elements in the array:

```bash
INDEX=("${ANIMALS[@]}")
echo "${INDEX[@]}"
```

This will print:

```
DOG CAT CAW BIRD
```

For Question 2, if you want to show multiple elements from the array, you can specify the indices as separate elements inside curly braces "{ }" and separate them with commas ",". Here's an example:

```bash
INDEX=("0" "3")
for i in "${INDEX[@]}"; do
  echo "${ANIMALS[$i]}"
done
```

This will print:

```
DOG 
BIRD
```

If you want to print in the same line:

```
result=""
for i in "${INDEX[@]}"; do
  result+=" ${ANIMALS[$i]}"
done

# Remove leading space
result="${result# }"

echo "$result"
```

This will print as

```
DOG BIRD
```

Note that the elements inside curly braces "{ }" should be separated by commas "," without any spaces. Also, the indices in the array should be specified as strings, not as a single string with spaces in between.

Comment: You are right, I've corrected my answer. Perhaps copying mistake.